# Worklight: two users Same device Push subscription

Tags: push-notification, device, ibm-mobilefirst, udid

I have a scenario presented by business team that: one person has device and he subscribed for Push Notification, later on his wife use the **same device** and **subscribe** for Push on her account.

Now in this case:

1. will Push go two times to the same device?
2. Or, the previous device subscription will be **overridden**

Plus, my App **saves** all Push notification messages on user's devices (as transaction history) , shouldn't be the problem!

To handle this scenario, what could be the possible options?

I am using Worklight Consumer 5.0.5

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you subscribe with different user on a same device the old subscription will be deleted. This is done for security reasons, e.g. in case you sell/loose/give your device new user should not get notifications of old one.